# How to display huge variables in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

Some of my variables are huge (include tables with so many rows). When I try to see the variables via **variables view** in Eclipse, it shows a part of it, not the all. So, I need to  use **system.out.println("myVariable");** to see, what my variable contains, and this not an effective way.

Is there a way to get over this? Or do you offer a better solution than sys.out.println?

Comment: is this viewing variables in debug mode?

Comment: The *Variables* view allows navigating into every field of the object referenced by the variable, recursively. What aren't you able to see?

Comment: refactor your codes. use pmd kind of tool to analyze your codes.

Answer (score 0):

The best I would suggest is to use the display view:

```
    menu -> window -> show view -> debug ->display
```

inside the display view, type the variable name, right click and select `display`. Still if short, use the `sysout` statement there, and again, right click and select display.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In *Variables* window we have grid with list of variables and a field with variable signification below. Right click on this field => "Max Lenght ..."